# Can I Edit any data on a converted lead?

Tags: lead-conversion

We have some reports that look at opptys and accounts. Some, rely on the information that the lead had while it was a lead.

After some changes to the lead we use today, We need to edit data, within some of the converted leads, so the reports will comply to the requests.

Is there any way to edit these converted leads?

Comment: I believe you can't. There has been an idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BprXAAS posted and no response for 6 years.

Comment: See this link https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000170793&language=en_US

Comment: recreating leads effect campaign membership history and remove `Converted Lead ID` from record. It is only a workaround and has side-effects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The newest way to allow this was introduced in [Spring '17](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_sales_leads_view_converted.htm). The original answer has been preserved for posterity below.

---

You cannot modify a converted lead directly. Some global actions can invisibly modify those records, such as using the replace picklist value feature and merging record types, but no normal editing method (API, UI, etc) will be able to affect those records. As stated by regal in the comment on this question, there is a [pending idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BprXAAS) that has been around almost as long as I've been using salesforce.com (and back then, I was in technical support handing out this same answer as today). The "correct" method for updating the lead would be to export the archived data, modify it, insert them as new leads, and mass convert them back into the same account/contact as previously (but it won't link to the original opportunity). Of course, this method will lose the original conversion date, although you could log that in a custom field, but it's still a hackish workaround for something that should be available at least to administrators.

Comment: Blargh.  I was hoping beyond hope I'd find a nugget here on SE that would show how to edit Converted Leads.

As a side note, does anyone know when they started allowing you to DELETE them?  It seems(?!) like this is a relatively recent capability (or am I just confused that I ever tried before 2013?).

Thanks.

Comment: @AMM You've always (since at least 2005, when I started with SFDC) been able to delete converted leads. This has been a sticking point with many organizations. Like my answer says, there's a request for it.

Comment: Interesting.  I can only guess I've associated the inability to EDIT them with the assumption therefore that you could not delete them.  Oh well.  :-P  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In Spring 16 release there is new feature introduced "Update Fields on Converted Leads".

We all know that once a Lead is converted, the data is only accessible in a read-only fashion via the Converted Leads report. But now, users with specified permissions can update fields and  picklist values or Leads already converted."

See here more about that feature: http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_sales_leads_edit_converted_leads.htm

Thanks,
Rajendra

Comment: The correct link is here: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_sales_leads_view_converted.htm

Answer (score 2):

With the release of [Spring 16](http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_sales_leads_edit_converted_leads.htm) you can now update converted lead fields. On the profile (or permission set) you will need the following permissions:

User Permissions Needed
To update converted leads:  "Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation"
AND

"Update Records with Inactive Owners"